# Webservice for TLS 1.2 testing

Tags: java, web-services, jython

Our enterprise datawarehouse (EDW) sources data from many interanal & external sources. We use Oracle data integrator (ODI) as teh ETL tool to extract data from the sources. ETL jobs are executed using an ODI agent which is nothing but a Java process. One of the external sources for the warehouse is a webservice. Data is extracted from this webserice using Jython (wrapped within ODI). Jython as you might know is a Python variant which runs within JVM. The Jython job runs under the ODI agent (java) process and extracts data from the webservice.

Coming to the problem we are facing now- The external webservice provider has indicated that soon they will support only TLS 1.2 and will remove support for older TLS connections. The ODI agent is currently on JDK1.6 Update 33 and support TLS 1.1. We are planning to upgrade the ODI agent to Java 7 (which supports TLS 1.2) so that we will be able to connect to this webservice. The Java upgrade involves lot of work mainly to ensure that it does not break existing ETL jobs. If there are any impacts, we might not be able to upgrade. An alternate option is it create a separate Java process (outside of ODI)  running under its own JDK (which can be even Java 8) to connect to this web service.

Are there any risks in the above options? It is going to take a while for the provider to give the webservice which supports only TLS 1.2. Are there any public webservices which support only TLS 1.2 that can be used by for our testing? Can you please share them?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not entirely what you're looking for, but it might be wise to have two seperate development projects for both the old and the future ODI agent to keep things transparent. Especially when testing the new version. It's also advisable to set up a dedicated testing/QA environment for this.

Be sure to keep your production ODI repository safe, you could use a testing repository with some exported projects for this. Maybe this link below might be useful: https://www.redbridgesoftware.com/products/life-cycle-management-for-odi.html

Comment: Thanks JohanVC. More than managing this within ODI, I'm looking for public webservices that will help TLS testing.